# SELinux is not logging denials

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I'm trying to secure a Tomcat app (Confluence) with SELiunx. If I `setenforce 1`, the app breaks, so SELinux is definitely enforcing. The problem is I can't see any denials in messages or /var/log/audit/audit.log, the behaviour is the same in enforcing and permissive modes.

`ausearch -m AVC` results in `<no matches>`. I've also ran `semodule --DB` which hasn't made a difference.

OS is RHEL 7.9

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `CONFIG_AUDIT` kernel flag is set; at least that fixed the problem in my case (Android ROM development)